# Where is the documentation for the "jQuery.event.special" API (for custom events)?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm creating a fork of the [`textchange` jQuery plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event), which uses the `jQuery.event.special` API to create its own custom events (`textchange`, `hastext`, and `notext`).

I'm going crazy trying to find the **documentation** for the `$.event.special` API!  I've searched jQuery's site and found nothing that mentions the `special` functionality. I've found several blogs that talk about API and even reference [a link to it](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/#Special_Events), but that page does not talk about it at all.

Can someone please point me toward some documentation for this "special" API?  I'm mainly interested in jQuery's documentation, because I want to know the "official" source of this API.

#### UPDATE:

I looked at jQuery's source, and they use the `$.event.special` API for certain events (including `ready` and `hover`), so it's obviously not obsolete as I previously thought.

Comment: it is not called special for nothing

Comment: @ajax333221 Does that mean that the API is undocumented?  I've seen many plugins use the API, but they all seem to just "know how" to use the `special` API.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/ is the best source of info I managed to find. It seems well documented

Comment: I haven't seen any official documentation on these either. It may have been an internal feature that was blogged about by a very few people. To date, I've only seen [these](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/4/jquery-edge-new-special-event-hooks) [few](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/03/26/special-events) [posts](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/) on the topic.

Comment: @Ajax333221 Why don't you turn those comments into an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/

The site seems to be well documented and should have everything you should ever need to know about the jQuery Special Events.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That site has a great explanation of the usage of `$.event.special`, including the revision history!  Considering that it isn't officially documented by jQuery, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: this article refers to the jQuery extensions prior to 1.7, and @ScottRippey there is an "official" [article](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/) for that since 1.7.

Comment: @AvinashR Thanks for the update!  You should probably post an Answer with this info, so that it doesn't get "lost" in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

There is some official documentation here: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/

Comment: this documents refers to the jQuery extensions since 1.7, and they themselves acknowledge that the [Ben Alman's jQuery Special Events article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/) is still an overview of the earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Although it is true that there hasn't been any Official documentation on the `jQuery.event.special` there is a beta [tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/) (as of March 19 2013) documentation at [learn.jquery.com](http://learn.jquery.com/) since jQuery 1.7.

For anyone following older jQuery(prior to 1.7) should find it as Ben Alman's [article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/).

*Side Note: Ben Alman's [article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/) is also mentioned in the official [tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/).*

Comment: Thanks for keeping this info up-to-date!

Comment: @ScottRippey I'll try to add overview of it here itself, (once i got the time).
On another note, +1 for the plugin link.