# Yet another 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined '

Tags: javascript, debugging, function, typeerror

My chances are slim with this but I've tried a couple of solutions via Google but nothing seems to fix the 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined ', anonymous function:

[image]

It works if on its own with no other JS but when combined on the same page as other scripts I get the error.

The lines of code it refers to are the following with line 32 being the culprit. Line 32 is this line - `if ( resizeTimeout ) { clearTimeout( resizeTimeout ); }`:

```
var $event = $.event, resizeTimeout;

    $event.special.smartresize  = {
        setup: function() {
            $(this).bind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
        },
        teardown: function() {
            $(this).unbind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
        },
        handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
            // Save the context
            var context = this,
                args    = arguments;

            // set correct event type
            event.type = "smartresize";

            if ( resizeTimeout ) { clearTimeout( resizeTimeout ); }
            resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery.event.handle.apply( context, args );
            }, execAsap === "execAsap"? 0 : 100 );
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guessing you're loading a newer version of jQuery. It appears as though `jQuery 1.9` and later does not have the `jQuery.event.handle` property.

To my knowledge, this was never a supported property.

http://jsfiddle.net/xPJN4/

Comment: Ok, cheers for this. That code was taken from an tutorial that uses v1.8.3. What would be a good subsitute to that live of code?

Comment: @egr103: I'm not sure what that method does, so I can't suggest an alternative. It's too bad that a tutorial decided to use unsupported features.

Comment: Yeah me neither. Oh well. I even deleted that line but it doesn't fix what I'd hoped it would fix.

Comment: It's some kind of debouncing function. Where did you get that code from?

Comment: @Bergi I got it from here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/10/12/flexible-slide-to-top-accordion/

Comment: It uses the [event.special api](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8919620/1048572), and something seems to have changed with it in your version of jQuery. I'm not sure how to fix it, yet the `jQuery.` before `event.handle` seems initially wrong to me. Try to remove it

Comment: @Bergi I did remove it but it didn't fix the problem I hoped it would. The error disappeared though.

Answer (score 10):

I managed to figure this out by looking at the code, there is a method called "simulate" which you can use to "Piggyback on a donor event to simulate a different one.", "Fake originalEvent to avoid donor's stopPropagation, but if the simulated event prevents default then we do the same on the donor." This struck me as the purpose of "setting the event type in Brandon Aaron's tutorial

Instead of:

```
event.type = "myType";
jQuery.event.handle.apply(this, arguments);
```

Use:

```
jQuery.event.simulate('myType', this, event);
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I accidentally loaded the newest version of `jquery` in the head, then loaded an older version of `jquery` after it.  The older version didn't have the methods that I needed from the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error using older versions of jQuery and masonry.min.js - I no longer have the un-minified code!

Replacing:

```
b.event.handle.apply(d,f)
```

With

```
b.event.simulate('smartresize', d, f)
```

Sorted the problem and the scripts are working fine now, credit to @karl-forshaw for the fix... I would comment in replay but lack the reputation to do so!

Answer (score 0):

My error was fixed when I linked to jQuery Migrate.

*JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1*

No more errors. For me the isotope.js was causing this issue. Hope it helps random person. :)