# What is “jQuery.event.special”?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and I have been trying to look up the Bootstrap [transition.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/transition.js#L50) (line 50) code and figure out how it works in there. I have stumbled across the following:

```
$.event.special.bsTransitionEnd = {
      bindType: $.support.transition.end,
      delegateType: $.support.transition.end,
      handle: function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is(this)) return e.handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments)
      }
```

I have read the [documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/), but couldn't really understand much except the following:

```
 bindType: // the event you want to bind with 
 delegateType: // the event you want to delegate with
```

After some research I have found the following:

> Those are the special attributes for the transition end event that are made available for later use in transition.js.

I am trying to figure out things by reading this [article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/), but all I want to know is: what is `$.event.special`, what is the use of this line? What is it's common usage?

**P.S.**: I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919620/where-is-the-documentation-for-the-jquery-event-special-api-for-custom-events) question but it has more external links than the answer itself. Is there a clear canonical Q&A about the most basic use of `$.event.special`?

Comment: When learning math, you wouldn't understand much if you started with linear algebra. To understand jQuerys Extended Events, you probably need to have a good understanding of normal js, jQuery and events first. Maybe you have, I wouldn't know, but the link  to the official documentation explains it quite well. Still, interesting if someone could put it in newbie-terms :)

Comment: @Mackan , well you can say i have a basic understanding of that .. and yeah ur right abt the math thinggi .. but right now for me personally .. its a case of "learing to run.. before i can walk" :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> WHAT is the use of this line?

I'm assuming you meant the first line of code in your question. It basically defines bsTransitionEnd as an **alias** for the transition end event (the transition end event may vary from browser to browser - that is what the function *transitionEnd()* does : determine the proper transition end event for the browser. I've used webkitTransitionEnd here on, but it could be something else depending on the browser)

Why use an alias? It insulates any handlers that Bootstrap attaches using this alias (e.g. $('myBootstrapDialog').on('bsTransitionEnd', *Bootstrap's handler*) from any $('myBootstrapDialog').off('webkitTransitionEnd') that other code (say, your code or maybe another library) does - so the Bootstrap transition end animations would still work!

Why would you or another library do that? The webkitTransitionEnd is a standard event, so let's say you decide to add a transition end animation to a bootstrap dialog - you'd probably do $('myBootstrapDialog').on('webkitTransitionEnd', *your handler*) and later on you decide to remove the handler you should be going $('myBootstrapDialog').off('webkitTransitionEnd', *your handler*), but you miscode it as $('myBootstrapDialog').off('webkitTransitionEnd') - this removes all transition end events :-(.

But since Bootstrap attached it's handlers using 'bsTransitionEnd', the only way you could mess up bootstrap would be to do $('myBootstrapDialog').off('bsTransitionEnd') - not something you would do accidentally :-). So voila! Gone be the bugs where Bootstrap inexplicably stops working because of some small miscoding on your part.

The bindType and delegateType basically state that bsTransitionEnd is an alias for *transition events* attached directly, and ones that are delegated (bubbles). The handle is basically a filter function - all the triggered events basically go through this before the attached Bootstrap event handlers are called (if at all they are)

> what is $.event.special?

I'm sure you'd know most of it already - it's a way to hook into jQuery's event handling mechanism allowing you do large scale magic like do X on every attached click event on the page (imagine doing that one by one, at each and every place you've attached an onclick event), define your own events (with all the bubbly goodness and all which comes with it), hook in and spoof events by modifying the event object, etc.

> WHAT is its common usage?

I assume this was rhetorical :-) - you already have a couple of really good examples in the Ben Alman blog post you linked to

(paraphrasing) - let's say you do an AJAX submit and want to disable all clicks on the page (you probably don't want the user clicking on and navigating off to some other page via a menu, or changing a checkbox, etc.) and $.event.special.click should help you (of course it might be just easier / traditional to just overlay a transparent / partially transparent div with a Submitting... animation or something or not doing anything - after all, most users wait around to make sure a submit was successful, at least the normal ones :-))

Another use case is the one you saw in the bootstrap code, but like you mentioned, you usually don't have to go in and use this unless you're writing a library or something that you intend to distribute publicly.

Comment: @patatopeelings +1 for the effort , I'll go through ur answer , a huge thank you !

Comment: nice speech , thanks for taking the time , i would love an example .. somewhere in between ! ... that ws what i was looking for .

Comment: I think the best example I can think of would be the one from the Ben Alman article linked to from your question (section 4.1) where every element that has an onclick handler is styled to have the mouse cursor change to a pointer - http://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/EhLS6/

And here is a very contrived example :-) I came up with - http://jsfiddle.net/L5wg4yfx/1/ - it basically calls our extra extra extra function when ANY jQuery bound click happens on the page

Comment: Hi, you forget to pass  function (event) in your last jsfiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/5gtv5pw8/

Comment: @potatopeelings you could check it in the fiddle i postet: `$("#parent1").on("click", "div", function (???) {
        alert("1" + $(event.target).text())
    });` where ??? = event

Comment: Oh shucks! You are right - I totally didn't see that when I read your comment first time around. Thanks! 

But strangely enough, it works even without the event being passed enough.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.event.special
```

The jQuery special events API is a fairly flexible system by which you can specify bind and unbind hooks as well as default actions for custom events. In using this API, you can create custom events that do more than just execute bound event handlers when triggered--these "special" events can modify the event object passed to event handlers, trigger other entirely different events, or execute complex setup and teardown code when event handlers are bound to or unbound from elements.

The jQuery special event hooks are a set of per-event-name functions and properties that allow code to control the behavior of event processing within jQuery. The mechanism is similar to fixHooks in that the special event information is stored in`jQuery.event.special.NAME`, where NAME is the name of the special event. Event names are case sensitive.

As with fixHooks, the special event hooks design assumes it will be very rare that two unrelated pieces of code want to process the same event name. Special event authors who need to modify events with existing hooks will need to take precautions to avoid introducing unwanted side-effects by clobbering those hooks

```
 bindType: // the event you want to bind with 
 delegateType: // the event you want to delegate with
```

When defined `bindType: String, delegateType: String`, these string properties specify that a special event should be handled like another event type until the event is delivered. The bindType is used if the event is attached directly, and the delegateType is used for delegated events. These types are generally DOM event types, and should not be a special event themselves.

Comment: This is almost a repeat of the documentation  !